trying to configure password protection on aliased directory in apache
I have apache 2.4.57 on a windows server. I created a new folder that only needs to display files that can be downloaded. In the httpd.conf file, I added this:
Alias "/pw_files" "f:\www_shared\pw_files" 
<Directory "f:\www_shared\pw_files">
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable FoldersFirst SuppressDescription SuppressLastModified NameWidth=* IconWidth=20 IconHeight=20
    IndexStyleSheet /css/autoindex.css
</Directory>

I created a .htpasswd file in the f:\www_shared\pw_files with this:
AuthType Basic
AuthName "please enter credentials"
AuthUserFile f:\www_shared\pw_files
AuthGroupFile "c:/apache_php/apache/htpasswd_group2.txt"
Require group pw_files

I created a new user:
htpasswd -c f:\www_shared\pw_files\.htpasswd pw_user

I moved the output from .htpasswd into the .htpasswd file in c:\apache_php\apache
In c:/apache_php/apache/htpasswd_group2.txt I have:
pw_files: admin pw_user

I made these changes and restarted.
However, when I go to:
http://www.example.com/pw_files

it takes me right to view the contents of the folder, but I never get the prompt to enter the username and password. I'm not sure what I missed.

One of the big misconceptions is that Apache password protection and mod-rewrite rules must be placed in .htaccess files. That is false. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when
You clearly have access to the main Apache configuration and httpd.conf ; then it is recommended to place your access restrictions there in the <Directory "f:\www_shared\pw_files"> section you already have.
Second: your f:\www_shared\pw_files appears to be a directory and then AuthUserFile f:\www_shared\pw_files is incorrect as the AuthUserFile directive expects a file path.
Use AuthUserFile  f:\www_shared\pw_files\.htpasswd instead.
Then: .htaccess files are ignored unless enabled with the AllowOverride directive and the class of directives used in there are allowed.
Last: get rid of the Require all granted directive which basically removes all access restrictions:
Alias "/pw_files" "f:\www_shared\pw_files" 
<Directory "f:\www_shared\pw_files">
    Options Indexes
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable FoldersFirst SuppressDescription SuppressLastModified NameWidth=* IconWidth=20 IconHeight=20
    IndexStyleSheet /css/autoindex.css
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "please enter credentials"
    AuthUserFile "f:/www_shared/pw_files/.htpasswd"
    AuthGroupFile "c:/apache_php/apache/htpasswd_group2.txt"
    Require group pw_files
</Directory>


That fixed it, thank you!
